# CSSでflexを設定できたのですが、全体を中央にしたいです。

Tags: html, css

CSSでflexを設定できたのですが、全体を中央にしたいです。

```
</html>
  <body>
    <div class="flex">
      <p>0</p>
      <p>1</p>
      <p>2</p>
      <p>3</p>
      <p>4</p>
      <p>5</p>
      <p>6</p>
      <p>7</p>
      <p>8</p>
      <p>9</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

```
.flex {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.flex>* {
    flex-basis: 300px;
    background: #fff;
    text-align: center;
}

.flex>* {
    border: 1px solid #aaa;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

各行の flex アイテムの数と flex アイテムの幅が決まっていない限り、その状態で flex コンテナを中央に寄せることは **Flexbox では不可能**です。代わりに Grid Layout を用いることで、そのような動作を実現出来ます。

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, 300px);
  justify-content: center;
}

.grid>* {
  flex-basis: 300px;
  background: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <p>0</p>
  <p>1</p>
  <p>2</p>
  <p>3</p>
  <p>4</p>
  <p>5</p>
  <p>6</p>
  <p>7</p>
  <p>8</p>
  <p>9</p>
</div>
```